# Dynamically load multiple remote scripts with a callback?

Tags: javascript

I need to load 5 remote scripts dynamically, and only then call a certain function.

```
var ggl1 = document.createElement('script');
var ggl2 = document.createElement('script');
var ggl3 = document.createElement('script');
      ggl1.src='https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-app.js';
      ggl2.src='https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-firestore.js';
      ggl3.src='https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-storage.js';
      document.body.appendChild(ggl1);
      document.body.appendChild(ggl2);
      document.body.appendChild(ggl3);
```

right after this i have to call   `initFireBase();` which **depend** on these. If i put this function right after adding them, i will get an error.
How can i know when they finished uploading ?

I know  i have `.onload` on a single script, but not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
ggl1.onload = function() {
  initFireBase();
}
ggl1.src = '...';
// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

you can create a function that returns Promise and wait for all the promise to be resolved using Promise.all, and after all promises are resolved call your function "initFireBase".

```
var loadScript = function(uri){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = uri;
    tag.async = true;
    tag.onload = () => {
      resolve();
    };
  var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  scriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, scriptTag);
});
}

   var P1 = loadScript('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-app.js');
   var P2 = loadScript('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-firestore.js');
   var P3 = loadScript('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-storage.js');
```

then in Promise.all , wait for all the promises to be resolved

```
Promise.all([ P1, P2, P3  ]).then(() => {
     // call your call back

     initFireBase();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small `recursive` script to achieve what you are trying.

**Note** If your scripts are dependent one after other, then position will need to be in sync.

Major Dependency should be in last in `array` so that initial `scripts` can use it

```js
const scripts = ['https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-storage.js', 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-firestore.js', 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-app.js']
let count = 0

  
 const recursivelyAddScript = (script, cb) => {
  const el = document.createElement('script')
  el.src = script
  if(count < scripts.length) {
    count ++
    el.onload = recursivelyAddScript(scripts[count])
    document.body.appendChild(el)
  } else {
    console.log('All script loaded')
    return
  }
}
 
  recursivelyAddScript(scripts[count])
```